# Comparing file content in two different directories

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I have four files in two directories: `1.txt` and `2.txt` in one directory and `3.txt` and `4.txt` in another one. I want to compare the first pattern starting with word "query" in these text files and match the files existing in two different directories.
How can I do it?

Example:

**1.txt**

```
ABC
Query : JKLTER
```

**2.txt**

```
ABC
Query : PCA
```

**3.txt**

```
Query :JKLTER
XYSH
Query : ABC
```

**4.txt**

```
GFHHH
```

Using the command I could derive these two files from the directories just based on first pattern (starting with `Query`) matched.

```
Output :
Matched files : 1.txt 3.txt
```

Comment: so what should be the result?

Comment: hi @RomanPerekhrest I just added.

Comment: @shome. Not really. You have input but not expected output

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist is it fine now ?

Comment: @shome. Yes, thanks. You actually want something much less complicated than what I was thinking. This is why it is important to ask proper, complete questions.

Comment: Actually, one more question. You originally mention four files, but then go on to only talk about two files. Could you edit the question to either talk about two files, or to explain in detail the contents and expected results from the other files?

Comment: Thank you @MadPhysicist.I just added.Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that is hopefully close enough - else you can diddle around with it a bit to get it closer.

So, if you use GNU `awk` to find the first line containing the word `Query` in all the files in a directory and then print the last word on that line and the name of the current file, you will get this for your first directory `d1`:

```
awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' d1/*txt
JKLTER d1/1.txt
PCA d1/2.txt
```

And this for the second directory `d2`:

```
awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' d2/*txt
JKLTER d2/3.txt
```

You can then pass the output of each of those commands to `join` to have it join lines wherein the first field matches:

```
join <(awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' d1/*txt) <(awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' d2/*txt)
```

**Output**

```
JKLTER d1/1.txt d2/3.txt
```

---

You can get rid of the leading directory by changing into each directory before running `awk`:

```
join <(cd d1; awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' *txt) <(cd d2; awk -F'[ :]*' '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME;nextfile}' *txt)
```

**Output**

```
JKLTER 1.txt 3.txt
```

---

You can get rid of the common field used by `join` like this:

```
join <(...) <(...) | awk '{$1="";print}'
```

**Output**

```
1.txt 3.txt
```

---

If you only have text files and nothing else in each subdirectory, and there are actually spaces after the colon following the word `Query`, my solution can be simplified to:

```
join <(cd d1; awk '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME; nextfile}' *) <(cd d2; awk '/Query/{print $NF,FILENAME;nextfile}' *) | awk '{print $2,"matches",$3}'
```

**Output**

```
1.txt matches 3.txt
```